# Angular2 / CLI is the moduleId reserved word?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I got the latest cli and created a new test project.

```
       angular2 version: "^2.3.1"
"@angular/compiler-cli": "^2.3.1",
"typescript":            "~2.0.3"
```

In AppComponent I have this constructor:

```
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app works!';

      constructor() {

          let test1 = {
                id: 'test',
                moduleId1: 'moduleId1',
                moduleId: 'IsThisReserverdWord',
                moduleId2: 'moduleId2'
            };

          console.log(test1.moduleId1);

          let test2 = {
                moduleId: 'moduleId3',
            };
      }
```

It is very strange that the console log part is never hit and there is no exception. By removing the **moduleId: 'IsThisReserverdWord'** property it is all fine. So here is the question why the **moduleId** seems like a reserved word?
Or I miss something?

Answer (score 1):

moduleId is used to resolve relative paths for your stylesheets and templates as it says in the documentation.

ref: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-relative-paths.html

without module.id

```
templateUrl: 'app/components/my.component.html', 
styleUrls:  ['app/components/my.component.css']
```

see how the url starts from base path

but with moduleid we can make use of relative paths.

```
templateUrl: 'my.component.html'
styleUrls:  ['my.component.css']
```

Comment: In this example ModuleId is not the part of the @Component decorator here but a property of an object in the class. No reflection should encounter with the code part! What if we have a model generator produces entities by database fields where also have the field name moduleId? This means we cannot use the word moduleId anywhere in the code? If so it must lead at least to an exception or any warning to the user else the point of view of the code this is bug!

Comment: Your code will also work without module id it not a mandate to use it . And because u might have configured your tsconfig to use moduleid it takes it as system keyword

Comment: If we look moduleId as system keyword the complier should mark the code usage as error. Now it leads unexpected behavior.

Comment: @McLac yes your onservation is correct . I have submitted a issue in Angular github to check on it as i am also confused on this, [great for you to point it out if it is a bug] .the issue link https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/15286

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/15286#issuecomment-287607114 Its more of a cli issue as it wokring for some contributers

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/5509#issuecomment-287632114.its a design compromise they have made

Comment: Hope this answers your question good pickup got to know something good today cheers